# OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server returned message "ROW-00004: Invalid column datatype"

Tags: sql-server, oracle

The following SQL running in SQL Server

```
select *
from openquery(oracle_ls,'select xmlelement("Test") from dual')
```

returns the error

> OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "oracle_ls" returned message "ROW-00004: Invalid column datatype".

How to return Oracle XML type via linked server?

Answer (score 1):

OLEDB driver complains as the data type is not supported.

However when you convert the xml to string, it should work.

```
select * from openquery(oracle_ls,
'select xmlelement("Test").getstringval() from dual')
```